# How to identify the upper and lower surfaces while calculating the volume bound by two given planes?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, 3d, volume, multiple-integral

I wanted to know if there is some general method to identify the upper and lower surfaces for integration while calculating the volume bound by two planes.
My particular problem is: Find the volume of the region bounded by $x+z=1$ and $y+2z=2$ in the first octant.

According to the solution we are supposed to perform integration over two different volumes with different surfaces taken as upper and lower, viz.: Draw a line parallel to the $z$-axis and note that the upper surfaces are $2z+y=2$ over the triangle bounded by $x=0,$ $y=1$, $y=2x$, and $z=1-x$ over the triangle bounded by $y=0$, $x=1$, $y=2x$.

Now I know that the general method is to draw a line from $xy$ plane in the positive $z$ direction and identify the surfaces in the order in which the line touches the planes, but this method doesn't work for me, so is there any other way or should I try harder on the visualization part?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)